Get a list of all mounted file systems in Linux using prometheus
I used the following prometheus metric to get the available space under root directory, by changing mountpoint, I can get the available space for all other locations. How can I get the list of all mounted directories(similar result generated with df command in linux to be used for mountpoint) through prometheus or python?
node_filesystem_avail_bytes{mountpoint="/",fstype!="rootfs"}


You may find a solution here.
